Inkscape snap package unable to export png
Since inkscape got removed from the repositories and the official method to install is the snap package it is not possible to export pngs anymore. The button to select the folder/path is disabled, I can't enter anything and when I select svg it shows the path of the file being /run/user/xxxx/.... When I hit [export] it is complaining to enter a path. I guess that is an issue of the isolation of the process from snap as it works installed via ppa.

Is there a workaround for that, or do we fallback to ppas again? Maybe I can define that inkscape can access my home folder? Or I can run it in a specific mode?
I'm running ubuntu 24.04 where many 3rd party applications got a snap package - what makes my experience much worse.

Snap packages run confined which means they can only access specific parts of your file-system.. You can export from snap programs, but location needs to be a permitted area.  The confinement improves security, as apps can't make changes to important areas.

I'm neither a developer of inkscape nor snap. I can't decide how that thing is working. The point is: the app is not working as snap package as I'm not able to choose any destination where it should export.

You don't specify any actual folder (in your question), but do specify / which is OUTSIDE of permitted areas; ie. it should be able to explore to anywhere in $HOME or /home/$USER which is your user directory; but not anywhere higher than that, excluding /media/ and /mnt/ location if that is setup to be permissible. You don't need to be a developer, snap was documented when introduced years ago.

I can't type anything in the export dialog. I can't click on the button to select the folder. Yes, maybe inkscape has a bug. What now?

we should not discuss here. the comments are to clarify the question. @gui

Confirmed the behavior. It seems clearly a bug, and therefore off-topic for AskUbuntu. Please report the bug to the Snap author.

@user535733 thx, for the confirmation. I don't quite understand why it is off-topic then? I used the official way to install software in the latest ubuntu version. how to get it fixed in ubuntu seems to be legitimate question for ask ubuntu.

Why bug reports are off-topic is clearly explained at https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site . "How to get it fixed" is by properly reporting the bug to the Snap author (who probably does not hang out here) with enough information so they can locate and fix the bug in the code. Any other action is generally wasted effort.

instead of export, use "save a copy", then you can enter a filename

but "save a copy" and "export png" are two totally different things. you can not save a copy as png and even then it would most likely be an image of the whole document (in export you can chose what to export)

Try to uninstall the snap package and install it from ppa.
To install it from ppa:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install inkscape


thx, that is what I have done. it's sad that this seems to be the only solution. as ubuntu wants to be more user friendly it should not move everything to snap. the solution to open a terminal and enter commands executed as super user is either for advanced users only or dangerous.

@iRas: Hello, I'm glad you're out of use.
Using commands in the terminal does not have to be dangerous, but first investigate what causes the command to be executed.
add-apt-repository simply adds a repository, which is problematic if you delete that list. The basis of Linux is the terminal and the commands to run in it.

I recommend to uninstall the Snap package and use the AppImage from the official Inkscape repo by downloading it from here and following the instructions to run it:

To use, download the file. Then right-click on it and select to edit its properties, or use a terminal to make it executable with
chmod u+x <AppImage File>

To start the AppImage, double-click on the file or use a terminal:
cd <directory with AppImage File>
./<AppImage File>

[...]
If the AppImage won't start, and you get an error telling you about the AppImage requiring something called 'fuse' to run, see the AppImage documentation for instructions.


Geez that's terrible. If like me you're in a hurry and need a simple export you could put your file in a snap-accessible location and export from command line. Paths seem to be relative to the home folder.
This worked for me:
inkscape snap/inkscape/current/input.svg --export-filename=snap/inkscape/current/output.png

